# Loss Not Coverging in SGD

Tags: pytorch

I am using  PyTorch Linear Regression loss and my SGD loss is not converging.
Use case -

- I am using MNIST dataset and implementing an image classification to classify handwritten digit 0 and 1.
- Then using Logistic regression model :
  `model = nn.Linear(input_size,num_classes)`
- Created the custom loss function.
- Training the model where in I converted the labels from 0,1 to -1,1. Convert labels from 0,1 to -1,1
- Determine Loss.

---

```
  total_step = len(train_loader)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
       for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            # Reshape images to (batch_size, input_size)
            images = images.reshape(-1, 28*28) 
            #Convert labels from 0,1 to -1,1
            labels = Variable(2*(labels.float()-0.5))
            # Forward pass
            outputs = model(images)
            # we need maximum value of two class prediction
            oneout = torch.max(outputs.data,1)[0]
            loss = loss_criteria(oneout, labels)       

        # Backward and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()        

        if (i+1) % 100 == 0:
           print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}' 
               .format(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, total_step, loss.item()))
```

Loss output: 0.8445,0.6883,0.7976,0.8133,0.8289,0.7195. As you notice the Loss is not converging.
Expected result :
0.8445,0.8289,0.8133,0.7976,0.7195,0.6883 all the way to zero....

Comment: Please excuse my formatting. Appreciate any help and thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using as `loss_criteria`?

Comment: why are you taking `torch.max` over the outputs? what is `loss_criteria`?

Comment: loss_criteria is a custom regression loss function .                                             
'loss = torch.sum(torch.log(1 + torch.exp(-mult)))'.                                           I am taking max of outputs which is like : tensor([[ 0.2859, 0.5506],
[ 0.1532, 0.3645],
[ 0.0835, 0.3317],
[-0.3868, 0.3129]                                                                                       
Then oneout becomes tensor([ 0.1414, 0.9170, 0.2080, 0.1533, 0.4046, 0.1832, 0.6290, 0.5015] .Appreciate any inputs on this please.

Comment: What do you mean by "expected"? Is this the same from implementation in another ML framework? What what do you mean by not converging? Does it get stuck at `0.7195`?

Comment: I am using PyTorch. It does not get stuck at 7.95 the accuracy is really poor like less than 30%. Also the loss for SGD should decrease with each epoch which you might notice is not happening.